# exclude all documents which has certain properties

Tags: mongodb

This Meteor code needs to find all documents which do not have given properties namely `prop1` and `prop2`.
It is failing to do that, How can it be done? Thanks

`DisplayCol.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId(), prop1: {$ne: ''}, prop2: {$ne: /.*/}});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#exists) operator to check for property existence.

So in your case where you want to exclude docs that have either a `prop1` or `prop2` property:

```js
DisplayCol.findOne({
    userId: Meteor.userId(),
    prop1: {$exists: false},
    prop2: {$exists: false}
})
```